# []' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["results"] in flutter http

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch api data from internet. Here I am using flutter http package and for showing in the frontend I am using FutureBuilder. Here is the api link with authorization:

```
https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/products/
```

Here is bearer token so that you guys can check the data:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NzE1OTE2LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc2Mjk1MTYsImp0aSI6ImI0ZjY1OTkzYTVmZDRjOGVhOTZkN2VlOWIwYzg0NjYxIiwiaWQiOjV9.SBG_OnsZJ2jZ0gLJv8OBkXiffDyStWnV8uWWjAIieEQ
```

So here is the controller for getting data from the api

```
  Future getProducts() async {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("access");
    try {
      // var response = await http
      //     .get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
        "Authorization":
            "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NzE2MjY1LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc2Mjk4NjUsImp0aSI6ImIxOGYyOTljMTg4MzRlNTVhMDcwZjBlOTQ5MTEzZDYwIiwiaWQiOjV9.DfsLsUk7Y1LZgiGJ7C2HcRNTJZwJLKmQVD1RhNmcrho"
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return json.decode(response.body);
      } else {
        return Future.error("Something went Wrong!");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
```

And here is the frontend code where I am trying to show the data:

```
Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              width: 1600,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: productController.getProducts(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return ProductCard(
                              name: snapshot.data?[i]["name"],
                              price: snapshot.data?[i]["price"],
                              image: snapshot.data?[i]["price"]);
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ),
```

I have no idea why and how I am getting this error. I tried with Future method I get unexpected error Future or List expected but got jsonMap. I tired the same method before it works perfectly for me. But Now I am getting this error. Can you explain why and how to solve this issue?

Here is my Json Response:

```
{"status":"success","results":[{"id":1,"name":"Test","unit":null,"price":"72000.00","sale_price":null,"image":"/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png","category":null,"badge":null},{"id":2,"name":"Test Product 2","unit":null,"price":"12000.00","sale_price":null,"image":"/uploads/digital_display/products/Product_Create_Mobile_final.png","category":null,"badge":null},{"id":3,"name":"Test Product 2","unit":null,"price":"12000.00","sale_price":null,"image":"/uploads/digital_display/products/digital_display_dashboard_final.png","category":null,"badge":null}]}
```

Comment: edit your question and add the json response you get from the API.

Comment: @OMiShah added the json response

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access to data[index] field. But data is not a List. You should get data from **results** field. Like that:

```
snapshot.data?['results']?[i]
```

Full code representation:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Some extends Equatable {
  final Set<String> data;

  const Some(this.data);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data];
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future getProducts() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/products/'),
          headers: {
            "Authorization":
                "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NzE1OTE2LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc2Mjk1MTYsImp0aSI6ImI0ZjY1OTkzYTVmZDRjOGVhOTZkN2VlOWIwYzg0NjYxIiwiaWQiOjV9.SBG_OnsZJ2jZ0gLJv8OBkXiffDyStWnV8uWWjAIieEQ"
          });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return json.decode(response.body);
      } else {
        return Future.error("Something went Wrong!");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 600,
          width: 1600,
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getProducts(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?['results'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Text(
                          '${snapshot.data?['results']?[i]["name"]}, ${snapshot.data?['results']?[i]["price"]}, ${snapshot.data?['results']?[i]["price"]}');
                    },
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if so, also ``itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,`` needs to be updated. :)

Comment: not working @Ramil

Comment: @sakibOvi I edited my response. Provided full working code example. Please, copy this code and check on an empty project. I used flutter version v3.3.7